# How to escape and remove backslashes from url after ajax call back?

Tags: php

In php I tried:

```
$link = get_permalink(icl_object_id(349,'page',false, $lang));
$link = str_replace("\n", "", $link);
echo json_encode(stripslashes($link));
```

But I still get

```
"https:\/\/example.com\/it\/jiku\/jikubox\/le-mie-infografiche\/"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are encoding the URL as JSON, so use a JSON parser (such as `JSON.parse(string)` or one built into your Ajax library).

Comment: Thanks Quentin, thought I could do it in php but in js it's fine too.